# Connecting to network through Ralink Wi-Pi adapter

Tags: raspbian, networking

So I've got the latest OS of Rasbian, and just received a Wi-Pi adapter by Ralink.  I'm trying to get the pi to connect my network, but once I plug my adapter in I can't get past the start up.  When I booted the pi it goes through it's processes (configuring network interfaces, loading keymap, etc.), but when it comes to

```
OpenBSD Secure Shell Server: sshd...
```

It gets stuck until I either turn off the pi or unplug the adapter.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Usual suspect is the power supply. Best is to try using a powered USB hub.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I don't currently own a powered hub but I connected the adapter straight into the pi (instead of the hub I had it in before) and removed a my hub completely from the pi to save power and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a power issue, I would try getting a powered hub for the Raspberry Pi. This would allow you to power your USB devices from an external source. I recommend this [Raspberry Pi themed hub](http://shop.pimoroni.com/products/pihub#.Uut9ZKgo4sI).

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens on one of my two Pi's.
It usually does get past it after five minutes or so, but if it does not it could very well be a power supply problem. I have found in the past it is due to a network misconfiguration before (static IP setup on ethernet, etc). It may help to erase any previous config (if any), or connecting the adapter after you have booted into LXDE.